# Decimal out of range

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to store the decimal `140.2705893427` into a SQL Server 2012 table.  The column has a data type of `decimal(12, 10)` but I get the error:

```
{"Parameter value '140.2705893427' is out of range."}
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`decimal(12, 10)` means 12 total digits, 10 of which may be after the decimal point.

Your value of `140.2705893427` has 13 total digits, thus it is out of range.

Read [decimal and numeric (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) for documentation.